# what does "all unplayed" mean in itunes podcast management

Tags: itunes, podcasts

if i say keep all unplayed episodes of my podcasts, will that keep it if i only listen to 2 mins of the podcast or is a "played" podcast one that i fully listen beginning to end.

i want to make sure it wont delete my partially listened to podcasts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podcasts you only listened partially to will not get deleted with this option.
iTunes only considers fully played podcasts (beginning to end) as "played".

Podcasts you listened to only partially are also marked with the half filled dot instead of the completely filled to for new ones.
Episodes you already have finished don't have the dot at all.